# Select Query Not Loading Value For Newly Added Tables In Php Tag Inside Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is the PHP code that I am using in my blade file inside of a foreach loop

Code:

```
@foreach($Filter_query as $agm)
    <h4>{{ $agm->display_name }}</h4>
    @php
       $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','cartez') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
       $newvalue=$agm->attribute;
       $result = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT price FROM men-panjabi");
       $combo="";
       if($result){
            if($result->num_rows){
                while($row=$result->fetch_object()){
                        $combo=$row->price;
                }
                $result->free();
            }
       }
       echo $combo;

    @endphp
@endforeach
```

this is what my controller looks like

```
<?php
    $Filter_query = DB::table($attribute_table_name)
    ->select('display_name','attribute')
    ->where('filter', '=', 'Y')
    ->get();
?>
```

the select query in the php tag is not loading values for all table but for few table it does.

where is the problem?

Comment: the problem is the fact that you don't know how MVC works

Comment: what do you mean by  _loading values for all table but for few table it does_?

Comment: @madalinivascu I am able to run the query for few tables of my database the code works fine but for the rest of the tables, the code doesn't work. like if i write that select location from users- it gives me result. But for that query above, no value is loaded.

Comment: i don't see multiple tables, what tables are you talking about? database tables? or html?

Comment: why are doing sql in the view,this should be in the controller

Comment: database tables.

Comment: you mean the tables from here  ` DB::table($attribute_table_name)` ? what are the `$attribute_table_name` values ,where do they come from?